# How to set the VirtualDocumentRoot based on the files within

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up Apache to use the VirtualDocumentRoot directive but my sites aren't all exactly the same. Most of the sites have a drupal folder which should be the root but there are a few really old drupal sites, a few rails sites, some django sites, etc. that want the Document root to be / or some other folder.

Is there a way to set up VirtualDocumentRoot based on a conditional or is there a way to use RewriteRule/Cond to detect that / is the incorrect folder if there is a drupal folder or a public folder?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Wildcard ServerAlias, this is the default vhost if no specific vhost matches first.
  ServerAlias *.unicorn.devserver.com

  # Automatic ServerName, based on the HTTP_HOST header.
  UseCanonicalName Off

  # Automatic DocumentRoot.  This uses the 4th level domain name as the document root,
  # for example http://bar.foo.baz.com/ would respond with /Users/vosechu/Sites/bar/drupal.
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/vosechu/Sites/%-4/drupal
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance!

-Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there a way to set up VirtualDocumentRoot based on a conditional`?

**No** -- That's simply not how `VirtualDocumentRoot` works -- It picks apart a portion of the hostname and sticks it into a path.

---

`or is there a way to use RewriteRule/Cond to detect that '/' is the incorrect folder if there is a drupal folder or a public folder?`

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking here, but it sounds like "Is there a way to make Apache behave differently based on the contents of a directory?" - If so the answer is pretty much "No":
Apache just serves what it's given. It has know way of "knowing" if a directory is a Drupal site (It just sees a PHP file, and fires up a PHP interpreter because that's what it's been told to do with PHP files, and spits out the results the interpreter gives it back).

---

You seem to be trying to shove the square peg of your radically different sites into the round hole of `VirtualDocumentRoot` (which is really best suited to dead simple sites) -- In your case I think you really need to create separate virtual hosts for each site and manage their configurations separately.