# Apache - how do I create an exception for a vhost's VirtualDocumentRoot in httpd.conf?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, virtualhost, documentroot

I'm new to Apache, and I'm wondering if there's a way to configure `VirtualDocumentRoot` to create an exception for just one of my vhosts on my local server. Currently all of my sites are stored in folders with the convention `sitename.dev`. In `httpd.conf` I'm dynamically setting `VirtualDocumentRoot` based on the server name:

```
# get the server name from the Host: header    
UseCanonicalName Off

LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog /path/to/logs/access.log vcommon
ErrorLog /path/to/logs/errors.log

VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/%0
```

This works great for all of my sites with one exception... the document root for one of the sites should point to `exception.dev/src/php` instead of just `exception.dev`.

According to [the answer I found here](https://serverfault.com/questions/139850/how-to-set-the-virtualdocumentroot-based-on-the-files-within), it sounds as if `VirtualDocumentRoot` cannot be set based on a conditional. So I was hoping my problem could be resolved by setting an alias of some sort to point `exception.dev` to the right directory.

I've tried adding `VirtualScriptAlias`, but this prevents the Apache server from starting:

```
VirtualScriptAlias /path/to/vhosts/exception.dev /path/to/vhosts/exception.dev/src/php
```

I've also tried the same type of thing with `ScriptAlias` and just `Alias`, but still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oh, and if it helps, here's my output if I run `httpd -S`:

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using XXXXX.local for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

**UPDATE**:
I got this to work by modifying Shane's answer below as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exception.dev
    DocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/exception.dev/src/php
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    ServerAlias *.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/%0
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a virtual host with your "normal" config, the `VirtualDocumentRoot`, and another with the exception config.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default
    ServerAlias *.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/%0
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exception.dev
    DocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/exception.dev/src/php
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thank you _so_ much! i got this to work with two small tweaks: added an asterisk after `NameVirtualHost *`, and moved the exception config **below** the default config within `httpd.conf`. will post the updated code above.

Comment: @luke Do you mean below or above? Your edit has the exception above - that's potentially a problem because it will be used for any hostnames that don't match a configured `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` (like if you had `subdomain.somedomain.dev`).

Comment: You're right, that was a typo - meant to say that I placed the exception config **above**. Would that potential issue be resolved if I changed the default `ServerAlias` to `*` instead of `*.dev`? For whatever reason I'm just unable to get `exception.dev` to work unless it's placed above the default config.